# Prevent refreshing if the popup is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, gsp

I am having one GSP(Grails) page.On that page there are some links.if some one clicks on link the **popup** will be displayed.I have used **thickbox(Jquery)** for that.  Now I am refreshing my page after every 5 minute using simple java script. Now problem is even if the popup is opened page refresh and popup gets closed.  My Question is how to prevent that java script to stop refreshing if the popup is opened..? or any other solution for that..

Comment: It's really hard to follow your question and figure out what you are asking.  Can you reword it or post some sample code so we can figure out what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

- When the page loads define a variable `var numOfOpenPopups = 0;`
- Each time a popup is opened `++numOfOpenPopups`
- Each time a popup is closed `--numOfOpenPopups`
- Change your code that does the refresh to

---

```
function refreshPage() {
    if (numOfOpenPopups <= 0) {
        // existing code that does page refresh goes here
    }
}
```